# ASP.NET MVC 4 Code first, How add tables using Code first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

Im playing currently on visual studio 2012 asp.netmvc4 with simple membership. This will generate 5 tables after running.

My problem is how do i add additional tables? I tried by creating a new model and adding a DbSet on the context class but it will throw error saying dbo.model does not exist in the database. The table is not created.

Is there a standard way of adding a model that will generate a table without running db migrations command?

I even added this Database.SetInitializer(new HWMDContextInitializer()); on application start but the error is still there.

Comment: by the way this is using ef5 visual studio 2012 ultimate

Comment: Scrutinizing the code, i figured it out. There is an attribute InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute, that sets Database.SetInitializer<HWMDContext>(null); so even if there are changes on the model, the database wont be updated. After I added new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>() replacing the null, it already works.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this. It will give you the exact approach
    http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/first-impressions-of-code-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>());
```

Comment: added this on application start, Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<UsersContext>()); and i got error: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

Comment: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges needs the EdmMetadata table to check model compatibility. To set up things you might use DropCreateDatabaseAlways or CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initializers instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
automatically whenever you change your model schema, use data migrations.

For more information refer to the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx